# Laravel get Error: Call to undefined function table()!

Tags: php, laravel, web

I am new in laravel.
whene I want to run seed by this command: php artisan db:seed, I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Call to
>   undefined function table()

my two seeder class:

1- GroupTableSeeder

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class GroupTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
          DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
          DB::table('groups')->truncate();

          $groups = [
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Family',    'created_at' => new DateTime,         'updated_at' => new DateTime ],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Friends',   'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime ],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Customers', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime ],
            ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'CoWorkers', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime ],
            ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Teachers',  'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime ]
          ];

          DB:table('groups')->insert($groups);
        }
    }
```

2- ContactsTableSeeder

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Faker\Factory as Faker;

    class ContactsTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run() {

          DB::table( 'contacts' )->truncate();

          $faker = Faker::create();

          $contacts = [];

          foreach ( range( 1, 20 ) as $index ) {

            $contacts[] = [
              'name'       => $faker->name,
              'email'      => $faker->email,
              'phone'      => $faker->phoneNumber,
              'address'    => "{$faker->streetName} {$faker->postcode}                 {$faker->city}",
              'company'    => $faker->company,
              'created_at' => new DateTime,
              'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            ];
          }

          DB::table( 'contacts' )->insert( $contacts );
        }
    }
```

and also my DatabaseSeeder class:

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            $this->call(GroupTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ContactsTableSeeder::class);
        }
    }
```

please help me to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: where is the `use` statement for the DB class ?

Comment: i add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; to this 3 files. but still not working and getting same error

Comment: Can you show the whole Laravel error? More details could be in the error that can help you resolved that.

Comment: Seeding: GroupTableSeeder


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to undefined function table()

thats all the error shown in the cmd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting this up to test, I noticed that there's a syntax error:

```
DB:table('contacts')->insert($contacts);
```

There should be two `::` when calling `DB::table` there. This may be a copy/paste to SO error, but I think it's the cause of the problem. I added the correct `::` and my seeders (which i copy/pasted from you) ran fine. I changed it to a single `:` and tried again, and I got the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Call to undefined function table()
```

Double check that you have the correct syntax there, and it may fix your problem.

Comment: BTW, to those saying to enter `\DB` or something like that, the seeders are in the root namespace, and so have direct reference to the `DB` facade without having the ``\`` and without including with `use DB;`.

Comment: yes you are right @james-funk. I had an syntax error. the problem is solved. thank's a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="{{ admin_base_path('auth/login') }}" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback {!! !$errors->has('username') ?: 'has-error' !!}">

        @if($errors->has('username'))
          @foreach($errors->get('username') as $message)
            <label class="control-label" for="inputError"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>{{$message}}</label></br>
          @endforeach
        @endif

        <input type="input" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans('admin::lang.username') }}" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback {!! !$errors->has('password') ?: 'has-error' !!}">

        @if($errors->has('password'))
          @foreach($errors->get('password') as $message)
            <label class="control-label" for="inputError"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>{{$message}}</label></br>
          @endforeach
        @endif

        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans('admin::lang.password') }}" name="password" value="{{ old('username') }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">{{ trans('admin::lang.login') }}</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: When you add the code try to format it and will look much nicer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DB class before using. Add this fully qualified namespace:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

to all your files wherever you use `DB`

Comment: i add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; to this 3 files. but still not working and getting same error

Comment: @rezaasghari have you ran `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import DB:

```
use DB;
```

Or add the slash

```
\DB::table(...)
```